# Flexbox - How do I fix the height and content position of two columns (left & right columns), and allow vertical scroll on a third (middle column)?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

```css
.container-parent {
  display: flex;
}

#master-column-left,
#master-column-right {
  flex: 1;
}

#master-column-center {
  flex: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-parent">

  <!-- #MASTER-COLUMN-LEFT -->
  <div id="master-column-left">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>
  <!-- /#MASTER-COLUMN-LEFT -->

  <!-- #MASTER-COLUMN-CENTER -->
  <div id="master-column-center">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>
  <!-- /#MASTER-COLUMN-CENTER -->

  <!-- #MASTER-COLUMN-RIGHT -->
  <div id="master-column-right">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>
  <!-- /.MASTER-COLUMN-RIGHT -->

</div>
<!-- /.CONTAINER-PARENT -->
```

I have a three column layout [flex-3] [flex-6] [flex-3]. I want to fix the position of the left and the right column and have the content remain fixed while the center column allows for vertical scroll. I can get this done without using Flexbox, but was wondering if there was a solution that I'm overlooking using Flexbox?

EDIT: I posted the markup above, but it's really not anything sophisticated at this point with just trying to test it, so that's why I didn't originally. I just simply want the middle column to scroll while the left and right remained fixed and wanted to use Flexbox to do it if possible. Worst case, I'll just position the elements without Flexbox.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you post the code that you tried?

Comment: Stephen, I updated the description above. Code isn't much as I'm just trying to test and get the layout to fix. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're ok with setting a fixed height on `.container-parent`, you can add two rules to your stylesheet:

```
.container-parent {
  display: flex;
  height: 300px;
}

#master-column-left,
#master-column-right {
  flex: 1;
}

#master-column-center {
  flex: 2;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Comment: I don't know if I can set a fixed height.. Unless it was something like 100vh? I wonder if that'll work? With the scroll to the center applied?

Comment: I knew it had to be something simple. Yes, that worked! Don't know why I didn't think about that sooner. Thank you!